# Exporting CSV shows ImportError: cannot import name 'CompressionOptions' from 'pandas._typing'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, importerror

When attempting to export to CSV the error below arises:

-I've tried updating pandas and then reverting to an older version with no luck.

```
~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal, errors)
   3143         Examples
   3144         --------
-> 3145         >>> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(name=['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
   3146         ...                   mask=['red', 'purple'],
   3147         ...                   weapon=['sai', 'bo staff']))

~\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from pandas._libs import writers as libwriters
---> 12 from pandas._typing import (
     13     CompressionOptions,
     14     FilePathOrBuffer,

ImportError: cannot import name 'CompressionOptions' from 'pandas._typing' (C:\Users\Bob\Anaconda4\lib\site-packages\pandas\_typing.py)
```

Comment: `conda update pandas` might work

Answer (score 16):

It seems that the problem is with the latest updates of the Pandas package ([Release version 1.2.0 and 1.2.1](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#history)).

To solve the problem, you can **downgrade the version to "1.1.5"** (The latest update on the 1.1 release). For doing so, I recommend you remove the package first and reinstall it again.

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.1.5
```

I had the same issue and could resolve it with the above simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Update your pandas lib

```
pip install pandas --upgrade
```